# How to show that $n^2 = O(f(n-1)+n)$?

Tags: big-o-notation

This is from Ex. 0.2.(b) from "Computational Complexity" by Arora and Barak (2009):

One needs to find a non-recursively defined function $g$ s.t. (1) $f = O(g)$ and (2) $g = O(f)$, where $f(n)=f(n-1)+n$ for $n > 10$ (and $f(1) = ... = f(10) = 1$). Solution booklet says that  $g(n) = n^2$, but I cannot see how to prove (2) i.e. I cannot show that for some $c$, $n^2 \leq c(f(n-1)+n)$ for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(n)=f(n-1)+n = f(n-2)+(n-1)+n = \\
=\cdots =\\
=n + (n-1) + (n-2)+ \cdots +(n-(n-10)+1)+f(n-(n-10))$$
Hope, You can finish from here.

Comment: Thanks, got it.